# Pager in Render Array

Tags: 7, theming

In a custom module I have a block defined and the function that builds the block returns a render array. In that render array I am looking to create a pager for my content since it is a listing of items.

If I run [pager_default_initialize](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/pager_default_initialize/7) during my query building like so this automatically adds a pager to the **top** of the block.

```
$total = $query->countQuery()
  ->execute()
  ->fetchField();

$page = pager_default_initialize($total, $per);

$query->extend('PagerDefault')
  ->limit($per)
  ->range($page * $per, $per);
```

I want to have more control over the pager, like adding it to the bottom of the block. If I remove the `pager_default_initialize` from the query building code like so, I can stop the pager from automatically being added.

```
$total = $query->countQuery()
  ->execute()
  ->fetchField();

$page = pager_find_page();

$query->extend('PagerDefault')
  ->limit($per)
  ->range($page * $per, $per);
```

So, the question is, how do I add the pager to my render array so it renders the pager at the bottom of the block?

My render array currently looks like this:

```
$content['results'] = array(
  '#type'       => 'container',
  '#attributes' => array(
    'class' => 'results',
  ),
);

if ($data->rowCount()) {
  foreach ($data as $record) {
    $content['results'][] = array(
      '#theme' => 'CUSTOM_NODE_THEME',
      '#node'   => node_load($record->nid),
    );
  }
  if ($per > 0) {
    $content['results']['pager'] = array(
      '#theme' => 'pager',
    );
  }
}
```

The theme_pager() is not being run when the block is rendered.

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. I knew as soon as I asked the question I would find the answer!

First off, the query building code must not run `pager_default_initialize`, like so:

```
$total = $query->countQuery()
  ->execute()
  ->fetchField();

$page = pager_find_page();

$query->extend('PagerDefault')
  ->limit($per)
  ->range($page * $per, $per);
```

The pager render array should be created like so:

```
$content['results']['pager'] = array(
  '#pre_render' => array('CUSTOM_PRE_RENDER'),
  '#theme' => 'pager',
  '#variables' => array(
    'total' => $total,
    'per' => $per,
  ),
);
```

And then run `pager_default_initialize` in the custom pre render function:

```
function custom_pre_render_intialize_pager($_element) {
  pager_default_initialize($_element['#variables']['total'], $_element['#variables']['per']);

  return $_element;
}
```

This code will only work to add a single pager to the block and may not work if there is more then one pager on the page.